# Manipulating the shapefile and made a zoom effect of city districts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing, scale

I need TopoJSON file for use in Power BI with a map where the city districts are zoomed/scaled and placed outside the country in the map.
Here is a map I have made in ArcMap Desktop  https://webguru.no/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/zoomOslobydelar.png by using the  "Scale" tool in ArcGIS.

Is it possible to manipulate the shapefile in QGIS and copy city districts to the right side of the map like the image (url) above?

Comment: Do you want to move the coordinates of the features?

Comment: You already asked the same question two years ago and already got some thorough answers. The question of that time has been closed for lack of clarity. you re-ask now the same one with the same lack of details ... what do u expect **exactly** ?